# The expansion formula in Maple with coefficients over $\mathbb Z_2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, maple

How to calculate the following equality in Maple

$A =  (x_1 + x_2 +x_3 + x_4)^{11}.x_2.x_3.x_4 = ?$

$B = (x_2 + x_3  + x_4)^{11}.x_1.x_2.x_3.x_4 = ?$

Here the coefficient of expansion in $\mathbb Z_2.$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it belongs on a site about maths software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as easy as:

$\qquad$A:=((x1+x2+x3+x4)^11)*x2*x3*x4;

$\qquad$B:=((x2+x3+x4)^11)*x1*x2*x3*x4;

$\qquad$a:=Expand(A) mod 2;

$\qquad$b:=Expand(B) mod 2;

Responding to your comment, to display the terms of $a$ in a single vertical column, you can use the following commands:

$\qquad$s:=[op(a)]:

$\qquad$for t in s[1..(-2)] do print(t+` `) od:

$\qquad$print(s[-1]):

Note:$\;$In the command print(t+` `), the three characters after the + symbol are back-quote, space, back-quote.

Comment: I want to output the result in a vertical row

Comment: Then you should to specify that in your question, and give an example of the desired output form. Also, your question isn't really a math question.

Comment: I want to output this result in a vertical row

$x1x2^14x3x4+  x1x2^13x2x4 + x1x2^13x3x4^2 + …$

corporeality 

$ x1x2^14x3x4+\\  x1x2^13x2x4 + \\ x1x2^13x3x4^2 +\\ \ldots$

Comment: Any change to your question should be edited into the question itself, not in a comment.

Comment: And how is this a math question?

Comment: B:=((x2+x3+x4)^11)*x1*x2*x3*x4;

expand(B) mod 2;

The ouput: $x_1x_2^{14}x_3x_4+  x_1x_2^{13}x_2x_4 + x_1x_2^{13}x_3x_4^2 + …$

But I want to output this result in a vertical row

corporeality 

$$ x_1x_2^{14}x_3x_4+\\ x_1x_2^{13}x_2x_4 + \\ x_1x_2^{13}x_3x_4^2 +\\  …$$

This is a math question.

Comment: You want a *single* vertical column for the entire result?

Comment: Yes! I want a single vertical column for the entire result

Comment: I edited in some commands to accomplish that.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!

Comment: It's not significant for these low powers, but for say `A := ((x1+x2+x3+x4)^311)*x2*x3*x4` it is more efficient to compute `Expand(A) mod 2` rather than `expand(A) mod 2` .

Comment: Agreed, the inert form. I'll make that change, it's at least as good in all cases, and much better for large powers.